# How many solutions for $37+\frac{3(x-1)x}2+3^{x+2}=y^2\,$?

Tags: diophantine-equations, exponential-diophantine-equations

How many solutions does the following exponential diophantine equation have in the positive integers?
$$37+\frac{3(x-1)x}2+3^{x+2}=y^2$$
The solutions $\,(x,y)\,$ I have found are: $\;(1,8),\;(2,11),\;(3,17),\;(4,28)$.

**Are the only solutions?**

Many thanks.

P.S. The equation has been built noting that:
$$27+37+0=64=8^2$$
$$81+37+3=121=11^2$$
$$243+37+9=289=17^2$$
$$729+37+18=784=28^2$$

Comment: Those are indeed the only positive integral solutions to the equation. But you haven't shown as to how you got them. And if you only want to check if they are the only ones, you could easily have searched WolframAlpha. However if you want a method then that's a different case.

Comment: @Mastermind817 I'd like to buy a vowel.  I've worked on it for 15 minutes, and got nowhere.  If no protocol violation, request hint or online (e.g. pdf) pertinent reference.

Comment: No Wolfram. It's not difficult to build exponential diophantine equations giving squares for few positive integers. For example: $x2^x+57=y^2$ for $x=3, 4, 6$.

Comment: Not all such equations involving both exponential and non-exponential terms will have easy solutions, in fact these problems will generally be very hard unless we are lucky that special tricks exist to solve them (e.g. modular arguments happen to work).

Comment: Usually, modulo arithmetics does not work if a solution exists. It would be interesting to see a proof here. Already the "usual" diophantine equations are not solvable in general (Hilbert's tenth problem) , exponential equations are in general even more difficult. What is the trick in this case ?

Comment: In general, if Wolfram Alpha presents a solution, there is no guarantee that the solution is complete. It might be able to do it in this case.

Comment: I wonder if one could reverse engineer a proof that those are the only solutions by looking at the algorithm(s) used by WA to compute those specific solutions.

Comment: Case 1: $x$ is even<br>
Let $a = 3^{(\frac{x+2}{2})}$<br>
 $3^{x+2} = a^2$<br>
Now the minimum difference between $l^2$ and $m^2$ is $2l+1$ where $l$ is the smaller one

Therefore, $y^2 - a^2 = 37+ \frac{3(x-1)(x)}{2} \ge 2a+1$<br>
Since $a$ is exponential it will rise very very quickly and so you can try putting smaller values of $x(2,4)$. It is clear that for $x \ge 6$, $2a+1$ is greater.<br><br>

Comment: Equivalent to no solutions to $81^{1+X}=12Y^2+4Y-8X^2-10X-15$ where $X,Y\ge0$.

Answer (score 0):

The following can be found with the 15-digit precision of Excel.

$$
(1,8)\quad
(2,11)\quad
(3,17)\quad
(4,28)\quad
(36,1162261467)\quad
(38,3486784401)\quad
(40,10460353203)\quad
(42,31381059609)\quad
(44,94143178827)\quad
(46,282429536481)\quad
(48,847288609443)\quad
(50,2541865828329)\quad
(52,7625597484987)\quad
(54,22876792454961)\quad
(56,68630377364883)\quad
(57,118871300538602)\quad
(58,205891132094649)\quad
(59,356613901615807)\quad
(60,617673396283947)\quad
$$
But WolframAlpha disagrees with the $x\ge36$ as seen [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=37%2B%5Cfrac%7B3%28x-1%29x%7D%7B2%7D%2B3%5E%7Bx%2B2%7D%3Dy%5E2%2C+x%3D36) so, if there are other pairs, it would take software with arbitrary precision to find them.

Comment: I used Python and Sympy library. I did not find any other solution except for the first four.